# apt-get not working on Ubuntu 16.04, problems with kernel packages

Tags: apt, 16.04

Any time I try to install anything with `apt-get` I get this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 483 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/49-teensy.rules'
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.31.33); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
  yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (4.4.0-24.43) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-24-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/49-teensy.rules'
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-24-generic
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/49-teensy.rules'
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
gives the same result

Comment: Does `apt-get install -f` fix you problem?

Comment: whats in you /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev file ?

Comment: @Dan `apt-get install -f` gives the same thing

Answer (score 9):

The problem is here.

cp: omitting directory '/etc/udev/rules.d/49-teensy.rules'

Remove that directory and re-run and everything should be fine.

Comment: Wow, that simple? Been banging my head on this for hours, just assumed this was nothing (it just means directory is empty so `cp` didn't copy it). I've added a bug-report for this issue so it hopefully won't be a problem in future: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1636922

Answer (score 3):

For me this helped!
Just remove all the linux-image and image-extra files, which are problematic by running:

```
$sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<>packagename<>.* /tmp/
$sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then update/install the latest one by running:

```
$sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```