# Errors encountered (by APT/dpkg) while processing linux-image-* packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

`sudo apt-get upgrade` returns:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic
 linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-firmware
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-39-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic
 linux-image-4.8.0-37-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-37-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-41-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-37-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-41-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I saw the related questions but their errors were a little different. I don't know if that's significant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code" when updating/ installing apps after interrupted update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855359/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-when-updating-installing-app)

Comment: Insufficient data to determine a cause or solution. We need the full session output showing the complete errors in order, not the summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem

[apt-get not working on Ubuntu 16.04, problems with kernel packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/807994/apt-get-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-problems-with-kernel-packages)

It comes from some modifications I had to make to use the Teensy microcontroller

Answer (score 4):

For me these two lines helped! Just remove all the linux-extra and linux-extra-image files, which are problematic and old.

For each package:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<PACKAGE-NAME>.* /tmp/
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then install/update the latest linux image file

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

Tengasui,

You can hardly work several kernels from single Ubuntu OS, so I recommend that you put obsolete versions "on hold".

Like this:

```
sudo apt-mark hold **package_name**
```

for example

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic
```

Probably you'll need only the latest kernel **linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic** and associated linux-firmware.

Try also:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Having single isolated error you can post and we can more know than brazillion of combinations of errors in dozen variants of kernels.

Comment: Okay, i've held everything but these 3:    


     linux-image-4.8.0-41-generic    


     linux-firmware    


     initramfs-tools    


when I run dpkg i get the following problem:    


E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.   

 
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-41-generic with 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to have multiple kernels. Since only one is used to boot from the others are automatically inactive. It is an advantage to have multiple kernels in case one fails. I have 4 kernels.
Since in your case all kernels fail I suspect your drive or partition is out of space or has not sufficient space left.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this, which happened during a fresh install of ubuntu.
It happened because my boot partition was too small (100MB), and the installation wasn't able to copy all the files it needed.

FIX: enlarge the boot partition to 200MB, and then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

**you sources.list file in /etc/apt/ directory is corrupted please do following things that will do everything for you guys.**

```
//first remove the source.list file don't worry
      rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then run this command in the terminal

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

and this would create a sources.list file automatically.
then run this

```
sudo apt -f install
```

> Best regards ... Mehdi Filban