# dpkg error after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04. However, I am getting this error with respect to miktex:

```
Removing miktex (2.9.6650-1) ...
miktexsetup: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version
`CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by miktexsetup)
dpkg: error processing package miktex (--remove):
installed miktex package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
miktex
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: miktex was already installed in my system with Ubuntu 16.04. This problem occurred when I upgraded to 18.04

Comment: What do you want to do: remove this package or upgrade it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, it seems `miktex` has not yet been updated to work with Ubuntu 18.04.  I recommend using `texlive` instead:

```
sudo aptitude install texlive
```

You can remove the `miktex` package:

```
sudo aptitude -f remove miktex
```

However, fully removing `miktex` is more complicated because the package is just an installer.  If you installed it in your home directory, look in `~/bin` for remnants.  Otherwise look in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Hi, so by the time I saw this answer I had already tried something that works - https://askubuntu.com/questions/893788/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-linux-image-4-8

But thanks for the suggestion of installing texlive!